# How to include kde extra cmake modules with fetch content

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project that uses some KDE libraries which itself uses ECM, but at this step, the build failed to find the ECM modules, How can I properly Include the ECM with FetchContent here is what I have tried,

```
# Fetch https://github.com/KDE/extra-cmake-modules.git
FetchContent_Declare(ECM
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KDE/extra-cmake-modules.git
  GIT_TAG        v5.112.0
)

# Make Available ecm
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(ECM)

# Fetch https://github.com/KDE/kwindowsystem.git
FetchContent_Declare(kwindowsystem
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KDE/kwindowsystem.git
  GIT_TAG        v5.112.0
)

# Make Available kwindowsystem
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(kwindowsystem)

# Fetch https://github.com/KDE/knotifications.git
FetchContent_Declare(knotifications
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KDE/knotifications.git
  GIT_TAG        v5.112.0
)

# Make Available knotifications
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(notifications)
```

Error

```bash
[cmake] -- Could NOT find ECM (missing: ECM_DIR)
[cmake] -- 
[cmake]  * ECM (required version >= 5.112.0), Extra CMake Modules., <https://commits.kde.org/extra-cmake-modules>
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FeatureSummary.cmake:464 (message):
[cmake]   feature_summary() Error: REQUIRED package(s) are missing, aborting CMake
[cmake]   run.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   build/_deps/kwindowsystem-src/CMakeLists.txt:10 (feature_summary)
```